# MVC calling different method with same parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, model-view-controller

I have a Controller that have 2 method with same parameters But if I call it I got an error

```
Several actions that matched the request were found:
```

I think that I must change Map routing to accomplish that but I dont know how to do it

My methods :

```
 public IHttpActionResult RecuperarMenu(short idInstalacion,string secretKey)

public IHttpActionResult RecuperarClasesColectivas(short idInstalacion, string secretKey)
```

My route map

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            namespaces = new[] { "WebServicesRestAPI.Controllers" }
        }
        );

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the controller that contains your methods is a WebAPI controller (it is derived from the **ApiController** class). Correct?

Thus, being a WebAPI controller:

1. It is configured not by means of the MapRoute method, but by means of the HttpConfiguration.Routes.**MapHttpRoute** method (by default it is configured in the ~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs file):

   ```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```
2. The names within the controller should follow the GET/POST/PUT/DELETE pattern (or should be explicitly mapped by you).
3. If your methods correspond to the GET operation, they should differ by arguments (you have the same arguments if your methods).

Comment: Yes it is derived from API Controller, and they both are get,
But I dont want to use different arguments, I want to have only 2 arguments on both and be able to call the method specifying the name of the method( or something like that)

Comment: Imagine the WebAPI framework: it has two Get methods with the same arguments and it receives a Get request. Which method should it call? You should distinguish them either by arguments or split into different controllers.

Comment: Yes but they got Differents name method, So I should be able to call 

"RecuperarMenu" or "RecuperarClasesColectivas" methods  i mean

something like domain.com/api/Recuperador/RecuperarMenu/?idInstalacion=50&secretkey=ererdf
instead of domain.com/api/Recuperador?idInstalacion=50&secretkey=ererdf

There is no chance to do something like this?

Comment: You can use the first call. However to do this, you should have two WebAPI controllers (your RecuperarMenu and RecuperarClasesColectivas) with the appropriate get methods.